# Merge [azure-storage-tables] into [azure-table-storage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are two similar tags: [azure-storage-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage-tables) and[azure-table-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-table-storage). The first has 780 questions and the second has 525, but correct name should be Azure Table Storage. It would be better to retag all 780 questions and burninate [azure-storage-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage-tables).

Another reason to do thing this way is name unification with the [azure-blob-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blob-storage) tag (storage type in the middle of the name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This request is completed, [azure-table-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-table-storage) is the only active tag now.