# Merge [azure-storage-blobs] with [azure-blob-storage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Can we merge [azure-storage-blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage-blobs) with [azure-blob-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blob-storage) and keep [azure-blob-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blob-storage)?

Number of questions tagged under those tags:
[azure-storage-blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-storage-blobs) - 5126
[azure-blob-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blob-storage) - 1651

If you see the other storage type table, it has a format azure-**storagetype**-storage: [azure-table-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-table-storage)

So for blob storage type, the [azure-blob-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-blob-storage) tag makes more sense.

This is similar to [this SO Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345724/7920473).